# Should I change the css style in my file or in the original file

Tags: css

When I want to change for example the style of a bootstrap button how should I do that:

1. Remove the css class in the bootstrap file and create a class in my css file with my settings
2. Leave the original css file and create a class in my css file with !important to overwrite the original file settings.
3. There are surely other ways...

What is the best my also considering upgrading to new bootstrap.css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to:

1. Leave the bootstrap file untouched
2. Modify the class in your own stylesheet
3. Load your own stylesheet after the bootstrap CSS

You have the benefit of not having to use `!important` and you can still update bootstrap.
Note: although you can update the bootstrap-file, you still have to test your page to see whether the update broke something, but this will at least assure you that you didn't lose any work

Answer (score 0):

1.) Make a backup of the file and just edit the file as you please. I wouldn't create multiple files with !important since you'll lose track of things pretty fast.